# Why does Appengine sometimes change the content type?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a JS app that sets an iframe URL targetting my appengine service. Intermittently the returned page has a content type of 'application/json' instead of 'text/html'. Repeating the invocation always serves as "text/html".

This is what Chrome captures

```
Request URL:http://www.clevernote.co/app/editpopupG.jsp?u=https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1mc_hXOOP-PppCn3GebeGREBRDKLSXp2R1R2ij2_ki_A&exportFormat=html&t=google%20integration&i=1mc_hXOOP-PppCn3GebeGREBRDKLSXp2R1R2ij2_ki_A
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:oauth2-token=; JSESSIONID=DHwIAl
Host:www.clevernote.co
Referer:http://www.clevernote.co/app/main.jsp
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.77 Safari/537.1
Query String Parametersview URL encoded
u:https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export

Response Headersview source
    Cache-Control:no-cache
    Content-Encoding:gzip
    Content-Length:1544
    Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Date:Sun, 23 Sep 2012 02:49:37 GMT
    Server:Google Frontend
    Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

If I reload the page, the response is correctly "text/html"

Content ...

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- CSS -->
<link href="../css/cnw  ... etc
```

Comment: The url above is not from Appengine, so how does this relate to Appengine?

Comment: The url **is** from Appengine! I'm happy to specify it as http://clever-note.appspot.com if that helps.

Comment: I get "Error: Server Error" if I try that url?

Comment: That's correct. The URL I posted is from within my app, and contains a link to one of my documents which you have no access to. It's designed to be called as an iframe from within my app, not by pointing a browser at it directly. 

I truly appreciate the effort, but you aren't going to gain any insight to my problem by calling the URL. One of two things will happen, either you'll get the response I pasted above (ie. Content-Type 'application/json', or you'll get the response I pasted above with Content-Type 'text/html'. In both cases, the HTML content is identical.

Comment: what is the actual content that is returned? is it html or json? if html, do you have correct doctype etc?

Comment: I've updated the question with the HTML content. To reiterate, the content doesn't change, it just intermittently gets served with the wrong content-type.

Comment: App Engine is not changing the content type - you're setting it or failing to set it somewhere. And without seeing your code, we can't possibly figure out where or why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the content type directly in the servlet.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)...{ 

      response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");    
      //...        
}
```

Comment: Thx, but I'm already doing this, and also setting the http content-type header in the servlet (well JSP). It seems that sometimes the Appengine front-end ignores it.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting content type in your HTML document:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: Thx Andrei for the suggestion. I'll try it and monitor the results.

Comment: This is a terrible idea, and a poor substitute for setting the content type correctly.